# Red X shown for connected drives

Tags: windows-7, file-management, network-drive

I am getting a red X on drives that are connected and accessible. It only happens to network drives, not local drives. Here is a screen shot:

[image: Red X in Windows 7 network drives]

Any ideas how to correct this problem?